# Flexbox position element at the bottom over scrolling images

Tags: html, css

I have a felxbox item that is just a group of images being rotated. I want the div to live at the bottom of the page which is always going to be height of 100vh. But I want it to overlay on top of the rotating images. This is what I imagine I need:

```
 ----------- 
|   images  | 
|           |
|           |
|           |
|    btn    | <--- floating over images
 -----------
```

Not sure how to achieve this with flexbox I tried to absolutely position the element, but I want to make sure there is no other way to do this with flexbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any code?

Comment: How exactly are the rotated images placed on the page? Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better assist you.

Comment: use position:fixed?